# parsley.js wrong data-type

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have a form that's being validated by parsley, but parsley seems to be screwing up.  The element in question is defined like this:

```
<input class="num-selector" type="tel" name="gift_amount" data-min="20" data-type="digits" required>
```

However, stepping through the debugger reveals it's being validated as `data-type="phone"`, which causes validation to fail.  (Unless somebody is buying a gift certificate worth over a billion dollars, but that's clearly a fringe condition.)

Has anybody heard of anything like this -- parsley screwing-up the `data-type`?  Ever run into code that picks a fight with parsely.js and corrupts its data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you use `type="tel"` in your input and parsley automatically recognizes it as phone number, not digits. Should be:

```
type="number"
```

Or just `text`.

Also there is no such attribute as `data-type`, you should use `data-parsley-type="digits"` instead. Same with `data-min` should be just `min` or `data-parsley-min="20"`

So your code can be:

```
<input class="num-selector" type="text" name="gift_amount" data-parsley-min="20" data-parsley-type="digits" required>
```

Look at the [Validators list](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-list) on official documentation.

Comment: Yup, that was the reason.  Looks like `type="tel"` was in there to bring up the number pad when a mobile user entered it.  Unfortunately, removing that introduces other problems.  (Remember that Simpsons episode where it was revealed that Mr. Burns was alive only because his massive collection of health problems somehow balanced each other out?  The form I'm debugging is kinda like that.)  But that's beyond the scope of this question.  :-)